# "Mouse over" event in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, mouseevent

I'm trying to make a python script were if you put your mouse over an element in tkinter something would happen.I know i could make a function that repeats via `after` and make an `if statement` but i think there might be an easier way. The `onmouseover` event from HTML is an exemple of what I want.
Thanks in advance!
My code:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, PhotoImage
root=Tk()
c=Canvas(root, width=500, height=500) # width and height are placeholders here
root.title("wdihihfwaheuih") # the title too
imag = PhotoImage(file="example.pgm")
image = c.create_image(250, 250, anchor="c", image=imag) # <-- element i want to "onmouseover"
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read up on [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) and

Comment: i read and nothing helps me

Comment: yeah thanks that works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind events to Canvas items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786877/how-to-bind-events-to-canvas-items)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what to do:

```py
#Create element called 'elem'

#Binding hovers
def on_start_hover():
    #What you do when the mouse hovers

def on_end_hover():
    #What to do when the mouse stops hovering

elem.bind('<Enter>', on_start_hover)
elem.bind('<Leave>', on_end_hover)
```

Comment: what type is the "elem" is it a PhotoImage? I get an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 45, in <module>
    game = Main()
  File "main.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.camicon.bind("<Enter>")
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'bind'

Comment: "elem" has to be a Tkinter widget, you can put the Photoimage on a label or button and then bind that.